# Using a Loop to extract CSV data into an object

Tags: python, pandas, loops, csv

My problem is quite difficult to explain and I'm unsure if it's even possible to do what I'm asking, but I will try my best to explain.

Basically, I have a CSV file with data, and I want to extract specific cells and set them as a value in an object. Each row in the CSV contains information about an individual item. Currently, I have it hard coded using the pandas library and by doing df.iloc[0][1], etc. However, I want to be able to loop through the whole CSV and extract individual cells and add them to multiple objects, so I don't have to hard code every row manually.

Hopefully, the code will help show what I mean:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Options.csv')
```

My Class:

```
    class Option:
    def __init__(self, type, name, S, K):

        self.type = type
        self.name = name
        self.S = S
        self.K = K
```

Current Extraction from CSV:

```
o1 = Option(df.iloc[0, 1], df.iloc[0][2], df.iloc[0][3], df.iloc[0][4])
o2 = Option(df.iloc[1, 1], df.iloc[1][2], df.iloc[1][3], df.iloc[1][4])
```

etc.

I still want to be able to select individual values of each option, for example, print(o1.name), o6.type, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to iterate over every row from 0 to the maximum of rows in the document. For each iteration you create a new instance of the Option class.

Here is some example code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Option.csv')

row_amount = 5 # put the amount of rows that the csv file contains here or get it with pandas 

options = []

for row in range(0, row_amount):
    option = Option(df.iloc[row, 1], df.iloc[row, 2], df.iloc[row, 3], df.iloc[row, 4])
    options.append(option)
```

Comment: Would it sill be possible to select individual options using this code. For example: print(o1.type)

Comment: yes of course, you can choose any element of the options list by using the following syntax: options[x]. Which means that you can use the following line to print the type of the first row: print(options[1].type)

Comment: Okay, Thanks, that makes sense. Final question, how do I iterate through the list of options, to allow me to perform methods from my class. I have tried a for loop but keep getting errors.

Comment: Just figuired it out!

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a list of of your Option objects:

```
options = df.apply(lambda x: Option(x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4]), axis=1)

options_list = options.values.tolist()
```